# How to VNC into an existing X session?

Tags: linux, fedora, vnc

Would like to be able to connect to an existing X display, so can access my work environment and everything I left open from home. I vaguely remember something about using x11vnc in the past. But the package does not exists for Fedora 11, so I am thinking there is some built in method now.

**NOTE:** I connect to my work machine through a VPN so password protection is all I need security wise.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [x11vnc](https://github.com/LibVNC/x11vnc), It will attach to a running session and let you share the desktop. If you run it as root to connect to an xdm session, you will need to do some research into Xauth as it can be a bit fiddly to set up.

Edit to add: Karl Runge no longer appears to be maintaining the original [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) however development is continuing on [github](https://github.com/LibVNC/x11vnc). Or you could do as suggested below by @ivan-talalaev and use x0vncserver.

Another advantage of this server is that it supports alot of the advanced VNC features used by [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) including large bitmap caching and file-transfer.

Comment: If you go this route, be aware that you might hit the problem hinted at with this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/19855/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-a-login-sessions-xauthority-file

Comment: okay so x11vnc still the go. So where is the fedora package for it :(

Comment: Have a look here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/x11vnc

You might not have much luck though. Fedora 11 is too new. Try installing the Fedora 10 packages.

Comment: it also has a long standing and well documented bug that crashes the server constantly with many standard window functions and the code is orphaned and will likely never be fixed.

Comment: @Scott please provide links. Also If you could suggest alternatives I would be happy to update my answer.

Comment: x11vnc is deprecated, use x0vncserver instead (see an other answer)

Answer (score 20):

According [documentation](http://tigervnc.org/doc/x0vncserver.html) **Tigervnc** has support for this.

> **x0vncserver** is a TigerVNC Server which makes any X display remotely
> accessible via VNC, TigerVNC or compatible viewers. Unlike Xvnc(1), it
> **does not create** a virtual display. Instead, it just shares an existing
> X server (typically, that one connected to the physical screen).

```
x0vncserver -display :0
```

Make sure `vncserver` isn't already running, or you'll get the error `failed to bind socket: Address already in use (98)`

Comment: Just note you will usually need to specify vnc password file too: `x0vncserver -display :0 -rfbauth .vnc/passwd`

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-start-a-vnc-server-for-the-actual-display-scraping-with-tigervnc/

Comment: For the record, Debian provides the package `tigervnc-scraping-server` for this use-case

Answer (score 3):

If you're using KDE at work, KDE already has a VNC server built in.

Presumably, GNOME does too.

Comment: -1 - Those create new sessions, don't use the existing one.

Comment: Robert Munteanu: no you are mistaken.

gnome has vino and you can dinamically bind vnc to an already running X session.

Comment: @cstamas - the original answer gave no indication of it - a name/link/config sample would be appreciated.

Comment: @Robert: http://www.gnome.org/~markmc/remote-desktop-2.html

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=266981 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=1592817 have information on enabling vino from command line

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you might want to look at [NX](http://nomachine.com/).  It is usually much faster than VNC over the Internet, and I know you can configure it to be able to access the running X session on the console.

Answer (score 1):

x11vnc (http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/)

Answer (score 0):

Use xrfb.

Edit 2022-04-05: xrfb is, no my knowledge, not the same as xvfb. Someone suggested an edit changing this to xvfb, but I think xvfb is not actually an answer to the question of how to VNC into an **existing** session.

But xrfb no longer exists in debian/ubuntu, it seems, and seems to generally have been disappeared from the Internet.

So my answer was fine 13 years ago, but not a good answer today.

Comment: A link to the home page would be much more useful.

Comment: here we go: 
XVFB -> https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml

Comment: XRFB is not XVFB, is it? @Nakamoto

Answer (score 0):

I did a fairly elaborate setup for a customer site that might be appropriate for you.

> This is based on a configuration I did
> for a customer. They wanted the
> following:
>
> - that users could remote-desktop into an already-running desktop
>   running on the system console;
> - that users could initiate a session running on the console if one wasn't
>   already running, and then use that;
>   and
> - that other users could connect to an already-running desktop, sharing
>   access with the user who was already
>   logged in.

[See the details here](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/x11vnc+setup).

Beware the security implications too.

Answer (score 0):

VirtScreen may be also interesting option/wrapper , helping in setting up x11vnc with xrandr : https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen

Also: Extending your X11 Desktop using VNC https://ogbe.net/blog/moar_monitors.html